# Op-amp simulation

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, frequency, gain, gain-bandwidth-product

I am not sure what's the mistake I am making in the below simulation.

Below is an [MCP660](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20002194E.pdf) non-inverting op-amp with a gain of 3.

Case1:
Input: 1 MHz;
Offset: 0.5 V;
Pk-pk amplitude: 0.2 V

[image]

Result:

[image]

The output gain is close to 3, and the input and output frequencies are same.

But if I increase the input frequency alone to 5 MHz, I get this result:

[image]

Why is there a 60 mV additional increase in the output voltage? Shouldn't it be the same 600 mV?

I am trying to test the GBWP and slew rate with this op-amp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like what is called "gain peaking". There is a section in the data sheet (4.4.2) all about this. In short, the input pin capacitance (circa 5 pF) is, in effect in parallel with R2 (1 kΩ) and, the reactance of this parasitic capacitor starts to reduce the effective impedance at the inverting input to ground. This means that the gain increases with frequency.

- So, at 1 MHz, Xc = 32 kΩ and, this is just beginning to be significant.
- At 5 MHz, Xc is ~6 kΩ and causes gain to increase a little more (as you observed).

One remedy is to use a resistor in series with the non-inverting input so that the signal arriving at that input is reduced by an amount and, that amount of reduction will roughly equal the gain increase due to the "gain peaking" effect.

- Maybe a 1 kΩ resistor in series with the input will resolve this.

Another remedy is to have a capacitor in parallel with R1 (2 kΩ) that is about 2.2 pF but, it's a bit hit and miss getting the correct value to balance the unpredictable parasitic capacitance of the input pins. For instance, 2.2 pF might work on one op-amp but 4.7 pF might be needed for another op-amp from the same batch.

Comment: Is it specific to the Op-amp? Or is this phenomenon is applicable to other op-amps too?

Comment: @Newbie all op-amps have this problem because all op-amps inevitably have input pin capacitance. Better op-amps have lower input capacitance of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me check with my simulation once and share my results after it.

Comment: @LvW you should possibly make it clearer (maybe by reposting) that your comment is aimed at the OP and not me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Andyaka, just one doubt. How did you arrive at the reactance values of 32kohms and 6kohms? How did you calculate?

Comment: @Andy aka I followed your advice

Comment: @Newbie Xc = 1/(2 pi f C)

Comment: Thank you @Andyaka.

Answer (score 3):

Just as the data sheet says,

There are two reasons for the peaking:-

1. Input capacitance to ground at the inverting input reduces the effective value of R2 as frequency increases and, (because gain is equal to 1+(R1/R2)), therefore reducing R2 results in higher gain at higher frequencies.
2. The inverting input pin's input capacitance in combination with R1 and R2 adds a pole in the loop response which reduces beta, R2/(R1+R2). This is good for improving stability but the added pole also adds more phase lag to the loop response which degrades stability more than the beta reduction improves it. That added loop phase lag reduces stability margins and high frequency peaking increases in amplitude with reducing phase margin.

The combination of these two effects result in the high frequency peaking which you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation (gain peaking) has one single reason:

The phase margin is not high enough. That means: When the loop gain crosses 0 dB the phase distance to the critical value (oscillation) is lower than 60deg. There are mainly two effects responsible for the degradation of the  margin:

(a) Frequency response of the opamps open-loop gain (is the opamp unity-gain stable?) and

(b) as mentioned by Andy aka: The input capacitance reduces- in addition to the opamps gain characteristic - the phase margin (it adds additional phase shift to the loop gain). A small capacitor across the feedback resistor can reduce this "gain peaking" (principle of ac-tuned voltage division).